# Show a group project to multiple users mysql

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have two tables the group_table where all the groups information is stored.

And i have a group_person_table where all id's which correlate to groups

I only want to display the group information to multiple users if they match in group_person_table

the database looks like this :

**Group_table**
person_id, group_id, groupname, groupdesc.

**Group_person_table**
person_group_id, group_id, person_id

currently i only have the following query:

```
"SELECT * FROM group_table WHERE person_id = $person_id" IN (SELECT person_id FROM group_person_table WHERE person_id =$person_id);
```

I currently am able to display all of the groups to all of the users but i only want to display the groups to the users if they're the same in group_person_table so user A and B are in group A so they both see Group A, if user A is in Group B, then User B wont see group B!

I'm displaying calling upon the data in OOP

> public function get_project($person_id){
>                                     //$sql3="SELECT * FROM group_table WHERE person_id = $person_id  ";
>                           $sql3="SELECT * FROM group_table WHERE person_id = $person_id";
>                                     $results = mysqli_query($this->db, $sql3);

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: But your query is nonsensical ?!?! :-(

Comment: @Strawberry I know i tried an inner join and an IN statement but both dont seem to work i cant seem to fix it

Comment: Well, now you know what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

One very important thing when creating a relation between tables is to decide where to keep the foreign key that will be used for linking them. Having a foreign key to the persons table in the group table, would restrict the group to one person only, which you obviously don't want. So, you can remove that column from the `group_table` and use only the `group_person_table` for the relations between the users and groups.

After adjusting this, your best choice would be an inner join, because nested select statements can really slow things down when working with larger data sets. And you want to get used to using the better approach :).

Your query would then be:

```
"SELECT * FROM group_table 
 JOIN group_person_table ON group_table.group_id = group_person_table.group_id 
 WHERE group_person_table.person_id = {$person_id}"
```